# Why does "Hi <user>" get stripped out of my posts?

Tags: support, signatures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

This bug or feature I observed while answering [How to call viewWillAppear delegate method of detail view of split view in ipad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606603/how-to-call-viewwillappear-delegate-method-of-detail-view-of-split-view-in-ipad/)

I wanted to write "Hi Vijay, [go to next line] text of my answer".
Stack Overflow consistently, even with edits, stripped the "Hi Vijay" part. Is this a bug?

Comment: This is by design. Salutations are discouraged on Stack Overflow. See Jeff's answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989).

Comment: So it actually really is a feature! Neat.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a bug.

As per [this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/93989#93989) from June 2011, salutations are automatically removed, as they don't add any valuable information to the answer. We would like to use the available space for actual content and not salutations.

> We now automatically remove salutations from posts as they are entered.

This applies to the beginning of the posts only. Note that even though "thanks" and their likes are not removed as they're a bit tricky to handle, you should probably refrain from including these in your posts as well.